# How to repeatedly refresh data from server using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, flask

I'm having a problem where when I use XML in JavaScript to get data from my Flask backend, the data that XML gets is just an empty string.

My XML code simply opens a new `XMLHttpRequest`, connects to the server, and every 10 seconds gets the response text which should change:

```
var output = document.getElementById('messages');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "/stream");
xhr.send();

setInterval(function() {
  output.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}, 10000);
```

My Python code just returns data from a variable:

```
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return app.response_class(var_that_changes, mimetype='text/plain')
```

I've searched all over stack overflow and I can't find an answer that doesn't completely use another technique, but maybe I will have to do that.

Comment: The code only sends a single `GET` request to the server, which will get a single response only. The text will not change simply because its re-copied to `output.html` every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wrap the part where you actually send the `GET` request in the `setInterval`. This makes it actually send a new request every 10 seconds. Otherwise, you're just getting the same data from the same request, which won't update.

You'll also want to wait for the request to complete by using `xhr.onload`, as the request is still pending when you attempt to retrieve `xhr.responseText`.

Here's what the code should look like:

```
var output = document.getElementById('messages');
setInterval(function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/stream');
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onload = function() {
    output.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
}, 10000);
```